# Enabling Enterprise Geodatabase in BigSQL Postgres 9.5.x install and ArcGIS Server/Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, st-geometry

I have followed Esri's ArcGIS 10.5 documentation multiple times over: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/setup-geodatabase-postgresql-windows.htm

Every time I try to Create a Spatial type for the database utilizing the ST_Geometry.dll that is for pgsql 9.5 placed in the appropriate associated directory, I get the following error:

"You must copy the latest ST_GEOMETRY library to the PostgreSQL software location.  Refer to the ArcGIS help topics for more details.  Connected RDBMS instance is not setup for Esri Spatial type configuration.  Failed to execute (CreateSpatialType)."

I get the same error if I try the enable Geodatabase tool as well.

I am pretty certain there is an issue with esri's ST_Geometry.dll and the BigSQL installation of Postgres, either the type of PostgreSQL installation or because the geodatabase tools are looking for a Postgres install in Program Files and Big SQL installs directly to C:.

Has anyone experienced this and/or know of a solution?  I would really prefer to use the BigSQL implementation if possible, but it doesn't seem like it is going to work.  In the mean time, I'm going to test with different installs/install locations.

Comment: Uninstalled BigSQL and did a regular PostgreSQL install from the main website and it worked fine.  Still not sure if it is a location issue, BigSQL-PostgreSQL installation type issue, or something else.

Comment: Did you review the System Requirements for ArcGIS 10.5 w.r.t. that version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Glad that you found the solution for this.

Just for anyone looking for a clearer guide, I have posted two youtube videos showing in details how to create enterprise geodatabase on PostgresSQL, one video for postgres for Windows and the other is for Postgres on linux (ubuntu 16.04 xenial)

The videos starts by downloading the correct version of postgres supported by your ArcGIS Platform. Then it goes through the installation process, it then illustates how to find the correct version st_geometry and copy it to the correct location in your postgres lib folder. Then finally creating the enterprise geodatabase.

I used ArcGIS 10.4.1 to demonstrate the video but the video is made in a general way.

I hope these videos will be helpful for whomever searching for how to create enterprise gdb on postgres. I understand the doc sometimes can be unclear.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQnljOFTspQWXfGVbMldxw23DQY6jbyDd

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed the issue is with the BigSQL version of PostgreSQL.  The only current solution is to install the original PostgreSQL from https://www.postgresql.org/

UPDATE: Looks like i forgot to update this last April, but for anyone that might still come by and read this and in the event it is still relevant:

I did get this to work with Big SQL moving the st_geometry.dll to the following path: `C:\PostgreSQL\pg95\lib\postgresql`